# How to read a variable from a file

Tags: c, file, variables, file-io

The program i am working on creates a file (about.txt) which includes a highscore section.

On line 12 of the .txt is...

Plain Text (With no highscore):

```
- with <0>
```

C:

```
fprintf(about,"-%s with <%ld>",highname,highscore);
```

I need to read the score from the file and test to see if it is larger than the current highscore before writing the new one.

i need...

```
if(score > highscore)
  highscore=score;
```

The only problem is how do i get highscore from the file.

I did some research myself and im sure that this is much easier than i am making it but when i looked around i couldnt find any way to do this.

Thank you.
/////////////////////////////////EDIT////////////////////////
Creating the file:

```
 FILE *about;
    fpos_t position_name;
    fpos_t position_score;
    ...
    fprintf(about,"\n\nHIGHSCORE:\n\n");
    fprintf(about,"-");
    fgetpos(about,&position_name);
    fprintf(about,"%s",highname);
    fprintf(about,"with");
    fgetpos(about,&position_score);
    fprintf(about,"%ld",highscore);
    fclose(about);
    ...
```

Getting Scores:

```
      FILE *about;
      about = fopen("about.txt","r");

      fseek(about,position_name,SEEK_SET);
      fscanf(about,"%s",highname);
      fseek(about,position_score,SEEK_SET);
      fscanf(about,"%ld",highscore);
      fclose(about);
```

Changing the variables (note.. highscore/highname are global variables)

```
if(score >= highscore) //alter highscore
    {
      highscore = score;
      highname = name;
      puts("NEW HIGHSCORE!!!\n");
    }
```

I get the error:

```
error: incompatible types when assigning to type 'char[3]' from type 'char'
```

On this line:

```
highname = name;
```

Name/score/highname/highscore declared here(in a header file):

```
char name[3];
char highname[3];
long score;
long highscore;
```

Comment: What exactly are you having difficulty with? Opening the file, getting the data from it, reading/parsing the text string once you pull it in, converting the text to a numeric value? Something else?

Comment: You would use the function fscanf.  It's defined in the same library as fprintf.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `fscanf`'s little known but very powerful regex feature, together with its ability to skip entries based on regular expressions:

Open the file, and skip the first 11 lines in a loop. Then read the score, like this:

```
FILE *f = fopen("about.txt","r");
int i, score;
char buf[1024];
for (i = 0 ; i != 11 ; i++) {
    fgets(buf, 1024, f);
}
fscanf(f, "%*[^<]%*[<]%d", &score);
printf("%d\n", score);
```

This will skip everything in the file up to the opening `<` bracket, then skip the bracket itself, and read an integer entry. Note that `%*` in the format string designates an entry to be skipped by `fscanf`. [Here is a snippet at ideone](http://ideone.com/j88OK).

**EDIT** -- In response to the additional question from your edit: you cannot assign arrays like that, you should use [`memcpy`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/memcpy/) instead:

```
memcpy(highname, name, 3);
```

Comment: when i attempt that it says error: expected ')' before numeric constant

Comment: @Bevilacqua You've got a syntax error somewhere then. If you post the change in an edit, I think we'd be able to spot it.

Comment: well i did this memcpy(highname, name, 3); ... but if i do what you suggested couldn't i avoid this completely.... If it isn't an array it won't work in other parts of the program. I am a little confused on how to do what you suggested

Comment: @Bevilacqua Absolutely, unless you need the name in addition to the score.

Comment: i do use the name for other parts and it works fine but maybe i could have the user supply the name again could you explain how to set up the loop

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use `fscanf` to do that; it's a bit like the inverse of fprintf.

Take a look at the documentation here:
http://cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/

Comment: I forgot to mention in my edit i also get the warning: format '%ld' expects argument of type 'long int *', but argument 3 has type 'long int'